# How to Calculate Delta Phi Psi between aligned pair of residue between Reference and Target Protein Structure in Pymol

Tags: pymol

How to calculate the Delta Phi Psi value i.e Difference in Phi and Psi values for the aligned residue pair between Reference protein structure and Target Protein Structure in Proteins?

I aligned multiple protein structures from the same protein family to a reference structure and now I want to calculate the Difference in Phi psi values for 'aligned' residue pair between Reference Structure and each Target Structure,  I have extracted the phi psi values using phi_psi command and I have the sequence alignment but I don't know how to extract Delta Phi Psi values for every aligned residue between Reference and Target.